# Google Map directions service

Tags: google-maps-api-3

You could see View example (directions-simple.html).

In the above example from and to is given by the user but i'm trying to get
 **From** automatically by detecting the user location through browser and **To** is been inputted by user.

I tried this dpaste.com/695949 but could not get it working.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a number of JavaScript errors in your example at http://dpaste.com/695949. I cleaned up the core of it, getting the geolocation and setting the map center there. I think you can then go from there to figure out the directions piece, but basically you'll need to have an input box for your user to enter the location they want to go to, and you can use the current map center as the starting point for your directions.

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

  function mapinit(position){
     directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:7,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcont"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    initiate_geolocation()
  }
function initiate_geolocation() {  
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_position_results);

            }
function handle_position_results(position){
    newCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    map.setCenter(newCenter);
}
```

Comment: Your map is there, but your CSS doesn't define a visible area. You're loading in http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css, but the CSS is looking for a div element named map_canvas. Change all instances of mapcont to map_canvas in your doc and it should work.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to add in an input form. The from you already have as the position, right? So add in an input text field and a button to submit. You might want to learn more about HTML forms here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/elements-form

Comment: .I know how to put a text box,where will i pass that text box value,i mean to which js function.

Comment: Create one like calcRoute in your original, only it has to take a destination value as an input

Comment: IL is the state of Illinois, where Chicago is. I understood your original post to say your starting point was the user's current location, which would be position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just ask the browser where the user is, through the [W3 Geolocation API Specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). Since this may changes across different browser and devices, I'd try with a library like [geo-location-javascript](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/).