# Get my current location using geolocation in dropdown menu

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i have this Google map that display directions from point A to point B
i want to use my current location instead of start point a which is Chicago in the code

the code so the code in this link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Map directions service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094463/google-map-directions-service)